# How to iterate an object/array in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

I have data input that looks something similar to

```
{
    "someone": {
        "semesters":[
            {
                "semester": "Fall",
                "grades" : [
                    {
                        "exam" : "Midterm 1",
                        "sections" :[
                            {
                                "section" : "First Section",
                                "grade" : 30
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Second Section",
                                "grade" : 40
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Third Section",
                                "grade" : 50
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "exam" : "Midterm 2",
                        "sections" :[
                            {
                                "section" : "First Section",
                                "grade" : 12
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Second Section",
                                "grade" : 21
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Third Section",
                                "grade" : 56
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "someone_else": {
        "semesters":[
            {
                "semester": "Fall",
                "grades" : [
                    {
                        "exam" : "Midterm 1",
                        "sections" :[
                            {
                                "section" : "First Section",
                                "grade" : 34
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Second Section",
                                "grade" : 3
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Third Section",
                                "grade" : 51
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "exam" : "Midterm 2",
                        "sections" :[
                            {
                                "section" : "First Section",
                                "grade" : 16
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Second Section",
                                "grade" : 80
                            },
                            {
                                "section" : "Third Section",
                                "grade" : 95
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to iterate through all the grades from multiple documents and make an output list that is sorted for all grades in the system. The data above should result in something like
First Section:

```
{ name : someone_else, section: First Section, grade : 34 }, 
{ name : someone, section: First Section, grade : 30 }, 
{ name : someone_else, section: First Section, grade : 16 }, 
{ name : someone, section: First Section, grade : 12 },
```

I want to be able to change the section section and be able to find data for the highest grade in each specific sorted to lowest.

Comment: sure there is, can you provide exact required output structure?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I went ahead and edited the main post, the sample output I'm looking for is a list of names/grades in order from highest to lowest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, we just need to convert the `grades` object to an array using `$objectToArray`, then we can project and sort the into the required output, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$grades"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      grades: {
        "$objectToArray": "$grades"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$grades"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      grade: "$grades.v"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      grade: -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fUHl6YPhjik)

Comment: This works! Thank you, is there also a way we can do this for data like the one in the post, I edited the format of the question, I just realized that data is within multiple arrays, and unwinding that may prove difficult

Comment: Yes, the structure is definitely not the easiest to work with but you can the idea remains the same, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uFliRGdayx)